# LFS: `bash: /tools/bin/gcc: No such file or directory`

Tags: gcc, path, linux-kernel, root, linux-from-scratch

I type

```
root:/# gcc
```

and somehow this happens:

```
bash: /tools/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, the $PATH works and is finding /tools/bin/gcc. I am chroot'd into $LFS and am on this step: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/linux-headers.html.

EDIT: Now `make mrproper` is no longer giving me a cannot find gcc error. Weird.

EDIT2: Nevermind,

```
root:/sources/linux-3.13.3# make mrproper
make: gcc: Command not found
```

Comment: Because you `chroot`ed, make sure that `gcc` exists inside your `chroot` jail at the specified location.

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, it is there (`root:/sources/linux-3.13.3# ls /tools/bin/gcc` gives `/tools/bin/gcc`)

Comment: Is `/tools/bin/gcc` a script? If so, does its interpreter exist? Maybe it's a symlink whose target doesn't exist?

Comment: @nneonneo `file /tools/bin/gcc`: `/tools/bin/gcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7b356215bd180e3e88cf2a04175dc0e3a373dda6, stripped`, `ldd /tools/bin/gcc`: `/tools/bin/ldd: line 117: /tools/bin/gcc: No such file or directory`

Comment: So if you run `/tools/bin/gcc` from your command-line that just fails?

Comment: @nneonneo `/tools/bin/gcc`: `bash: /tools/bin/gcc: No such file or directory`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50983/discussion-between-mypal125-and-nneonneo)

Comment: Did this get resolved?  I am having the exact same issue.  When I did the readelf -l test on all the executables in /tools/bin, they are show interpreter as /tools/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2.  Yes this problem still presists...

Comment: @squeegee Nope, sorry :/

Comment: Could you please post the result of `readelf -l /tools/bin/gcc | grep interpreter`? (ran from outside the `chroot` environment).

Comment: @squeegee See the questions on U&L.SE [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110184/lfs-7-4-chapter-6-7-make-gcc-command-not-found?lq=1) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137593/6-7-linux-headers-make-mrproper-fails-in-lfs-7-5?lq=1).

Answer (score 8):

For Googlers with x86-64 systems:

```
ln -sv /tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: Finally solved my problem, after days of googling and rebuilding. Thanks a ton! Mind explaining a bit?